# How to validate props that are passed to a component by value?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I've got a component that accepts `value` prop.

```
const MyComponent = ({ value }) => { ... }
```

I want this value to always be a number that is greater than 0 and less than 1000.

I only want to validate this for testing purposes in case I'm passing wrong value to the component so that I know immediately that I did something wrong.

Should I just write simple if statement that throws an error? Something like this?

```
const MyComponent = ({ value }) => { 
  if (value < 0 || value > 1000) {
    throw new Error("Value is not in range");
  }
}
```

Is there a better way?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don´t remember what I was trying to achieve back then but I know now what I was looking for, which is **Custom PropType validator**

```js
MyComponent.propTypes = {
  value: (props, propName, componentName) => {
    const val = props[propName];

    if (val < 0 || val > 1000) {
      return new Error(
        'Invalid prop `' + propName + '` supplied to' +
        ' `' + componentName + '`. Validation failed.'
      );
    }
  }
};
```

Maybe someone will find it useful in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

If i'm understanding correctly, the question revolves more around 'whats the best practice?'.

If so, you are looking at learning more about [Guard Clauses](https://learningactors.com/javascript-guard-clauses-how-you-can-refactor-conditional-logic/)